# adding array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

First, im new in PHP so please bear with me.

I just want to add an array with the `foreach` loop but I can't.

```
if($size > 0)
    {
        $resultArray = array();

        foreach($result as $hospital)
        {
            if($hospital)
            {

                $temp = array('result' => 'true', 
                'total' => $size,
                'id' => $hospital['id'], 
                'name' => $hospital['name'], 
                'address' => $hospital['address'], 
                'telp' => $hospital['telp']);

                $resultArray = array_merge_recursive($resultArray, $temp);
                //$resultArray = array_splice($resultArray, $i, 0, $temp);
            }
        }

        $this->response($resultArray, 200);
    }
```

I tried to create a `$temp` array and merge it to the final result, and finally print that final result (`$resultArray`) to the response.

The array is **successfully** merged, but **not in the way i want**. This is the JSON result :

```
{"result":["true","true"],"total":[2,2],"id":["1","2"],"name":["test","keyword"],"address":["alamat test","alamat keyword"],"telp":["123456","789"]}
```

What i want is something like this :

```
-0 :{
result: "true"
total: 2
id: "1"
name: "test"
address: "alamat test"
telp: "123456"
}

-1 :{
result: "true"
total: 2
id: "2"
name: "test2"
address: "alamat tes 2t"
telp: "789"
}
```

So the response should be an array with 2 items, and each items has some items.

Please kindly help me, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're trying to append an array, to an array, which can be done quite easily:

```
$resultArray = array();//outside the loop
//loop
$resultArray[] = array(
    'result' => 'true', 
    'total' => $size,
    'id' => $hospital['id'], 
    'name' => $hospital['name'], 
    'address' => $hospital['address'], 
    'telp' => $hospital['telp']
);
```

Job done. You could also use the `array_push` function, but that's a *function*. Functions equal overhead, and should, therefore be avoided (if it doesn't affect code readability). You use `array_merge` and `array_merge_recursive` if you want to combine arrays:

```
$foo = array(
    array('bar' => 'zar')
);
$bar = array(
    array('car' => 'far')
);
var_dump(
    array_merge(
        $foo,
        $bar
    )
);
```

The effect of `array_merge` here is comparable to:

```
foreach ($bar as $subArray)
    $foo[] = $subArray;
```

Comment: Yesss, this is what i mean, sorry for not using "append" word in the question. I cant accept now, need 4 more minutes

Comment: Your answer is the best. And thanks for detailed explanation, very helpful for me

Answer (score 1):

Im not totally sure how you want your final array to be, but this will put it like $resultArray[0] = array( //temparray ) etc..:

```
if($size > 0){
    $resultArray = array();
    $i=0;
    foreach($result as $hospital){
        if($hospital){
            $temp = array('result' => 'true', 
            'total' => $size,
            'id' => $hospital['id'], 
            'name' => $hospital['name'], 
            'address' => $hospital['address'], 
            'telp' => $hospital['telp']);
            $resultArray[$i][$temp];
            $i++;
        }
    }
    $this->response($resultArray, 200);
}
```

Comment: Yes, your solution is working. Thanks a lot. Its too bad i only can accept 1 question and 1 upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this -

```
$resultArray = array_merge_recursive($resultArray, $temp);
```

With this -

```
$resultArray[] = $temp;
```

Comment: i think we have some miss-com, but i fixed it already. Thanks a lot